# Encode in machine code an Assembly MIPS instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to encode the following `beq` instruction:

```
...
start: addu $8, $9, $10
       addiu $8, $8, 0x00FF7A01
       beq $8, $0, start
...
```

I know that it is a `J` format instruction so the division will be 6 bits to opcode and 6 to target address. `beq` opcode is `000100`, so I already have `0001000100000000`, but I don't know how to find the 16 remaining bits, any help?

Comment: I don't see any J-format instruction here

Comment: Oh, i was confused, since it was doing a jump to the "start" i thought it would be considered a J instruction, but afterall it's an I instruction! But I still can't manage to find the last 16 bits :/

Comment: well the sixteen remaining bits will the `immediate` value in `I` type instruction. So those remaining sixteen bits will be the address of `start`.

Comment: yes, I know, but how can i find that address?

Comment: It's not an address, it's an offset. You count the instructions between the `beq` and the label you want to branch to. For example `beq $reg, $reg, -1` would branch to the branch instruction itself.

Comment: by `How can I find that address` are you actually trying to calculate the address of start or you are viewing at the binary and trying to mark find those 16 bits. I am not getting what you are asking.

Comment: it's the number of words/instructions you need to jump

Comment: I need to jump back 2 instructions right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `beq $8, $0, start` is getting executed, the `PC` contains the address of next instruction. If the contents of `$8` and `$0` are not equal, there will be no jump, which means there will be no change in the value of `PC`.

But if the contents of `$8` and `$0` are same, you want to jump to the label `start`. In other words, what you want is this - you want the `PC` to contain the address of the instruction `addu $8, $9, $10`.

Therefore, the difference between **current value of PC** and the **value of PC in case of jump** needs to be calculated.

Number of instructions to jump = 3 (but in negative direction since we want the PC to jump to a previous instruction).

Binary Equivalent of -3 = 2's complement of (`0000 0000 0000 0011`)
which turns out to be `1111 1111 1111 1101`

Therefore, the 32-bit representation of this `beq` instruction will be:

```
0001 0010 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1101
```

[6-bits opcode of beq][5-bits register $8][5-bits register $0][16-bits of relative-address]

Answer (score 2):

In MIPS, during `beq` the offset to add to `program counter` is calculated as:

```
signextend immediate value

offset = (immediate value) << 2
```

New PC is calculated as:

```
pc += offset
```

Here, in your code, you want to move `pc` back 12 bytes or `3` instruction if `$8 == $0`. Hence to add `FFFFFFF4` as offset to `pc`, the immediate value that you will be requiring will be last 2 bytes of:

```
FFFFFFF4 >> 2 = FFFFFFFD
```

You can also understand this as:

```
Address
00000000 start: addu $8, $09, $10
00000004        addiu $8, $8, 0x00FF7A01
00000008        beq $8, $0, start
0000000C ...
```

while executing `beq` `pc` will be at `0000000C`. Suppose `$8 == $0` then `pc` should again become `00000000`. Hence `offset = final_pc - initial_pc = 00000000-0000000C`.
So,

```
offset = FFFFFFF4
```

and `immediatevalue` = last 2 byte of `((FFFFFFF4) >> 4)`. Therefore,

```
immediate_value = FFFD
```

Shortcut: Also instead of calculating this long, you can directly calculate number of `words` you want to shift your program counter. Over here you want to go `3 words` backward, hence `immediate_value = -3 = FFFD`. This also holds true if you want to go forward instead of backward.